# Big-O complexity calculation for a merge and sort function

Tags: c#, queue, complexity

I have the following code which basically takes a list of sorted integer arrays and merges them together removing the duplicates.

I have tried to do the complexity analysis and came to a rough conclusion that it may be O(n<sup>2</sup>) order. Could you please see if my understanding is correct here.

Also, if you could suggest ways to make the code better in terms of its running time, I would really be grateful.

If you need the implementation of `PrioQueue`, please let me know.

```
public ArrayList MergeMultiple(Object[] input)
{
    ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
    int activeArrayIndex = -1;
    int inputArrayCount = input.Count(); 

    // Keep track of indices of the arrays
    int[] indices = new int[inputArrayCount];

    // Keep track of whether the end has been reached for each array
    bool[] endOfArray = new bool[inputArrayCount];

    // Heap
    PrioQueue heap = new PrioQueue();

    while (endOfArray.Contains(false)) // O(N)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < inputArrayCount; i++) // O(N) 
        {
            int[] active = (int[])input[i];
            int index = indices[i];
            if (activeArrayIndex == -1 || (i == activeArrayIndex && !endOfArray[i]))
            {
                int value = active[index];

                // Add value to the heap
                heap.Enqueue(i + "|" + value, value); // O(N)??
            }
        }

        // Add to result
        if (!heap.IsEmpty())
        {
            activeArrayIndex = activeArrayIndex == -1 ? 0 : activeArrayIndex;

            string activeArrayIndexWithVal = (string)heap.Dequeue(); // O(1)

            string[] activeArrayObject = activeArrayIndexWithVal.Split('|');

            // Identifying active array
            activeArrayIndex = Convert.ToInt32(activeArrayObject[0]);
            int[] activeArray = (int[])input[activeArrayIndex];

            // Adding value to result object if not already in the array list
            if (!result.Contains(activeArrayObject[1]))  // O(N)
            {
                result.Add(activeArrayObject[1]);
            }

            // Update index list with active array
            indices[activeArrayIndex]++;

            // update end of array count list for current array
            endOfArray[activeArrayIndex] = activeArray.Length == (indices[activeArrayIndex]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If `N == number of input arrays` and `M == length of the longest input array` then your outer while loop will run `M` times with the check condition being `O(N)` so your outer loop is O(M*N)`. The inner loop runs`N`times and the heap insert is`O(log(N))`so your inner body is`O(N*log(N)). Resulting in a total complexity of `O(M * N^2 * log(N))`

Some review:

I find the entire code very confusing and hard to read. You keep track of different properties for the same array in disjoint helper arrays (`indices` and `endOfArray`) while they should be combined in a single state object.

Also your input is `Object[]` while obviously you expect a list of `int[]` so why not express that in your parameter directly like: `List<int[]> input`.

Your result is a non-generic `ArrayList` so it's really hard to know what the exact return type of the elements is. Reading through the code it looks like the elements get returned as strings which is probably very confusing for the user - why on earth would a method to which I pass a list of integer arrays return the merged result as an array of strings?

If I read your intention correctly then you want to merge the input arrays, remove all duplicates and return the result ordered. You can write that very nicely with LINQ:

```
public List<int> MergeLists(List<int[]> lists)
{
    return lists.SelectMany(l => l) // flatten into single collection
                .Distinct()         // remove duplicates
                .OrderBy(x => x)    // sort the result
                .ToList();          // build result list
}
```

Assuming all `N` arrays have the same maximum length `M` then [the complexity should be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799427/what-guarantees-are-there-on-the-run-time-complexity-big-o-of-linq-methods):

- `Distinct()` is in the order of `O(N * M)`
- `OrderBy()` is in the order of `O(N * M * log(N * M))`
- `ToList()` is in the order of `O(N * M)`

Which means the resulting complexity is `O(N * M * log(N * M)` so you have cut it down to linear in terms of number of input arrays and the code is significantly shorter, easier to read and maintain and very likely to contains fewer bugs.

Comment: Linq is inherently a .NET object. I just wanted to play around with something more generic. Three questions: First, shouldn't M be the *total* length of all the arrays combined, because, in the worst case the outer loop goes through all elements in all arrays. Second, How would I take into consideration the check for if the item already exists in the results array list? Third, is select many in the order of O(1), same as select?